# Roo Gem Check for Empty Worksheet

Tags: ruby, excel, rubygems

I am using the roo gem to parse Excel (xlsx) files. However, there are always some empty sheets in the file (workbook). Is there a way in roo to see if the sheet is empty or `nil`?

**Update**

```
wb = Roo::Excelx.new 'chapter_data.xlsx'

    wb.sheets.each do |sheet|
      wb.default_sheet = sheet
      unless wb.nil?
       code.....
      end
   end
```

The `wb.nil?` doesn't work it returns false.

**Update**
The only way I have been able to handle this issue is to rescue the no method error. I don't like handling it this way looking for a better way to check if the sheet is empty.

```
begin
   header_row = wb.row(1)
 rescue NoMethodError => err
   # do nothing, this sheet is empty can't find a way to check if it is empty pos
 end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured out the best way to check if the sheet is empty.

```
wb = Roo::Excelx.new 'chapter_data.xlsx'

wb.sheets.each do |sheet|
  wb.default_sheet = sheet
    if wb.first_row
      code.....
    end
end
```

The `wb.first_row` returns the index of the first non empty row.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could figure out how to check this without using a `rescue` was to do the following

```
unless wb.to_s == 'nil'
  code......
end
```

Stupid that I couldn't do a regular `nil` check. But this works.